# Specify a maximum size in d3 circle packer

Tags: javascript, d3.js, circle-pack

I'm using the d3 circle packing algorithm. It's set up to make inner circles occupy all available space. So if I have two circles of equal size, one containing three sub circles, and one containing 50, the three appear very large.

Is there a simple modification I can make to the script so that inner circles will not exceed a particular size - perhaps floating in the centre?

Source here:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/pack.js

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. While you can limit the size each circle can have quite easily, doing this in a context-sensitive way will require more work. In particular, you would have to check the size of the containing circle (possibly with respect to the overall size) as well as the number of children and their children. You may also want to check how far down in the nesting hierarchy you are to make these decisions.

Nothing of this is particularly difficult, but it wouldn't be a simple change.